# PIC32MZ2064DAR176 board with PicKit is not getting detected on windows system after installing MPLab X IDE

Tags: installation, driver, pic32, mplab-x

I have installed MPLab X IDE v6.15 on my windows PC. (Path: C:\Program Files\Microchip\MPLABX\v6.15)
I have installed the compiler as well.

After connecting the PIC32 MZ DA Curiosity board (PIC32MZ2064DAR176) with the system, it is showing as a Serial USB Drive, whereas it should appear as a PicKit device.

Tried re-installing MPLab X IDE v6.15 which is working on other systems. Same result.
Tried to connect the curiosity board on a different computer where installation and setup are already done. It is getting detected as a PicKit device there.
Also tried installing harmony configurator, updated all the plugins. It didn't help.

When I tried to flash binary on the board, getting these logs:

```
Transmission on endpoint 2 failed (err = -109)

A communication error with the debug tool has occurred. The tool will attempt to recover momentarily. A log of the error was created at C:\Users\M.W\HarmonyProjects\MyProject\firmware\sample.X\queuelogs\debugtool
Connection Failed.
Transmission on endpoint 2 failed (err = -109)
```